# binding key event in python using ctypes function

Tags: python, linux, keyboard

I have been trying to use python to bind my customize event to keyboard event with specific event code number like below

> ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event('0x24',0,2,0)

but as you already know

> windll

the library only worked on Windows OS.
how can I do something like this in Linux machines?
I read about

> CDLL('libc.so.6')

but I can't figure it out if this library is helpful or not?

is there another way to set keypress listener in OS level with python using the virtual key code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve as such?

Comment: i'm try to set my own event listener using only key code number .some thing like below :
keyboard_listener('0x24',custom_event_listener())

Comment: there is an existing solution pykeylogger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux input subsystem is composed of three parts: the driver layer, the input subsystem core layer and the event processing layer.
and the keyboard or other input event is all describe by `input_event`.

use below code and type in your Terminal `python filename.py | grep "keyboard"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8
import os

deviceFilePath = '/sys/class/input/'

def showDevice():
    os.chdir(deviceFilePath)
    for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        namePath = deviceFilePath + i + '/device/name'
        if os.path.isfile(namePath):
            print "Name: %s Device: %s" % (i, file(namePath).read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    showDevice()
```

you should get `Name: event1 Device: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`.
then use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8
from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select

def detectInputKey():
    dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')

    while True:
        select([dev], [], [])
        for event in dev.read():
            print "code:%s value:%s" % (event.code, event.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    detectInputKey()
```

`evdev` is a package provides bindings to the generic input event interface in Linux. The evdev interface serves the purpose of passing events generated in the kernel directly to userspace through character devices that are typically located in /dev/input/.and`select` is `select`.